# Can I tell if a track is in stereo?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes v.12.3.2.35, can I tell if an aiff song is in stereo or mono? I tried "Get Info" but I cannot find a tab regarding this. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "File" tab of the track info window has what you're looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a Terminal run the following command:

```
mdls -name kMDItemAudioChannelCount $name.aiff
```

Example:

```
mdls -name kMDItemAudioChannelCount /System/Library/Sounds/Basso.aiff
kMDItemAudioChannelCount = 2
```

If it shows 2, it's stereo.

Note that this assumes the file resides on a volume that is indexed by Spotlight.

Comment: Strictly speaking the result only yields that the file has two channels. It doesn't have to be real stereo (in the sense of two **different** channels) though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. I have concluded that I will not be able to use iTunes to determine if a track in my library has true stereo sound (as opposed to dual mono sound). Sorry to get away from my original question, but I did find a trial version of a utility that uses a custom-built algorithm to analyze audio files and determine their stereo content to test the CD "The Kinks Greatest Hits" (Catalog #R2 70086) on Precision Records & Tapes, Ltd./Rhino Records which according to the packaging consists of digitally remastered mono recordings except for one track. I used the utility to analyze several of the “mono” tracks and I was surprised to find that it determined the tracks were actually stereo files and the waveform indeed showed the stereo content overlaid on the audio waveform. I emailed the company and a representative told me that if their utility determines a file is stereo, it is in fact stereo. He said: "...it is possible there is some reverb or other effect that is causing the file to be stereo and that if these audio files that I think are mono were imported from a CD, especially a commercially bought CD, the chances of them being mono is almost 0; they are almost definitely stereo." I can only see this being the result of the Duophonic sound process by which a monaural recording is reprocessed into a kind of "fake stereo". I see that historically this process has caused confusion and disappointment for music buyers even up to the present.